# findById return null getting record inserted outside of Spring

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have a function in Spring that call an external API which create a record in the same BD that my spring project use. Example:

```
@Transactional
public MyObject processRequest(Long id) {
    Request request = requestService.findById(id);

    //This Api, call to another Project and create a record the same table used by the Entity "MyObject" and return the generated ID
    ApiResponse apiResponse = callApi(request);

    MyObject myObject = myObjectService.findById(apiResponse.getId());
    if(myObject == null){
        log.info("ID doesn't exist");
    }

    return myObject;
}
```

The problem is that "`myObjectService.findById(apiResponse.getId());`" (dao) return null, but the record exist in the db table beacuse it was created by another App when i called "`callApi(request)`".

Why i get null if the record exists?

Comment: Could be a timing issue. Your code makes a call to the API and then it looks like it right away attempts to `findById`. Has the API had sufficient time to create the record?

Comment: Hi, yes. Because It API brings back the ID, the id os correct, and It is autogenerated and autoincremented by MySQL tablet rules. I even added a 5 second sleep between the API response (with the id) and the findById.  and the same thing happens.  The findById returns null.  I have also tried the same findById from a get controller, just to test that it works and there it does return the record.

Comment: `apiResponse.getId()` returns a not-null `id`?

Comment: what exactly is callApi doing, and how are you sure that it has inserted the record by the time it returns? Check the SQL it issues, and also importantly, its transaction settings to make sure the statements it issues have been committed before the method returns; they are not visible to any other process until it commits.

Comment: @Chris The api performs some processing and inserts a record into the DB. Yes, I am sure that it does it because it returns the ID of the inserted record. I have even tried putting a Sleep before using the ID (which is not Null) and the same thing happens, that findById return null.

Comment: @ZackMacomber Yes, is not null, I print the object myObject and everything is fine.

Comment: Returning an Id value does not mean it committed the transaction. Check your sequence allocation on the entity- some allow preallocation which is set on persist/save calls without insert. Inserts occur on synchronization with the DB (mostly on flush or commit). And again, it is only visible to other processes when the transaction is committed in the database; the database itself isolates transactions from other processes (ACID principles of databases). So you'll need to show that logic and how you've setup your transactions to figure out what is happening

Comment: I forgot to indicate that my function uses @Transactional